# Spring cache and Spring data redis

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

1. **Spring cache + Spring redis**: Spring provides a caching abstraction package `spring-boot-starter-cache` which basically provides method level annotations to cache data with `@Cacheable`, `@Cacheput` and other annotations. I feel there are limitations to this: Caching a collection of POJO against a  property (for example: `Person.getId()` as the key from `List<Person>` as a return type). And the other limitation is searching. How do I query and search data in the cache provider?
2. **Spring redis**: Then there is `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` which basically contains: `spring-data-redis` and `lettuce`. Just using this package without a combination of Spring's Cache means that there has to be some kind of IoC introduced to switch between Database communication and Cache provider. But ofc, directly using redis has advantages in the sense of having better control is storage/retrieval/search/evict.

Which one to choose?

If #1 is chosen, how to gain more control over the caching mechanism (inserting collection/search)?

If #2 is chosen, should the IoC be provided on the service layer like: `API -> DB-Service/Cache-Service -> Repo`. Or a new layer, like: `API -> Optional-Cache-Service -> DB-Service -> Repo`